# How to track session in iis logs with classic asp app on windows server 2003

Tags: iis, windows-server-2003

I'd like to use my IIS logs to track sessions in my app, but don't have a session key being pushed along the querystring in my pages.

What's the easiest way to start tracking that in the log - put a querystring value in the iis logs, or is there a way to append session to the logs as a custom field?

Using 32-bit classic asp against windows server 2003 64-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS (since version 5, at least) lets you log cookies in the "W3C Extended" log file format. Add the "cs-cookie" field to your logs and restart your website, they'll appear there.

You will need log analysis software that supports tracing sessions via the cs-cookie field, however - but it largely isn't necessary as most log analysis follows paths-through-site and sessions by tracing the cs-referer header instead.

If you have large cookie strings then expect your site log files to balloon in size.